# Jabber server library in C++

Tags: c++, xmpp

I'm looking for a jabber server library in C++.
I tried glooxd but it's tough to compile, buggy and no activity since more than a year now.

What I'm trying to do, is to be able to build a process that accept xmpp stream, implement it own way to authentify and build custom rosters.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Swiften](http://swift.im/swiften/), a relatively new addition to the XMPP scene.  It's primarily used in the client [Swift](http://swift.im/), but also by [Spectrum 2](http://spectrum.im/), which can act as a server to clients.

In the [Swift git repo](http://swift.im/git/), there's also a tool called [Slimber](http://swift.im/git/swift/tree/Slimber), that acts as a [client in serverless messaging mode](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0174.html), and then presents that as a normal client interface.  The server parts of Spectrum 2 and Slimber may be useful for you to study.

Comment: Could you add more information about Swiften to this answer? It'll help avoid link rot (and improve the answer, too).

Comment: There. The question isn't very specific, so I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `libxmpp` project on Sourceforge. I don't know much about it. However, a number of years ago, I wrote a C++ layer on top of the `loudmouth` library. It's not hard to wrap the C library constructs in thin C++ classes.

Libxmpp: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmpp/

Loudmouth: https://launchpad.net/loudmouth

Comment: But those are clients libraries ? I need to build a server instead.

Comment: @ruddy I seem to recall Loudmouth supporting both servers and clients, but not certain on that. I dug through my links and found a page on xmpp.org with a list of known Jabber server project: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/. I'd start there and see if a library can be mined out of one of them.